# Slow and errors openening a new site after deploying solutions in SP2013

Tags: 2013, deployment, site-creation

We are running SP2013 and having often problems after deploying and creating a new site.

When the solutions are deployed, we create a site with powershell or from central admin  with de new deployed WebTemplate.

When we open the site we get one of the following errors:

- 403 FORBIDDEN
- The website declined to show this webpage 
  HTTP 403 Most likely causes: This website requires you to log in.
  What you can try:
  Go back to the previous page.
- The HTTP request to 'xxxx/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' has exceeded
  the allotted timeout of 00:00:00. The time allotted to this operation
  may have been a portion of a longer timeout

Often after we got the error and we refresh the page the site will load and work properly, but sometimes loading of the site takes forever and a reboot of the server is needed.

Comment: what's your server's specifications?

Comment: It's a development server that is running virtual. OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 with 24GB memory and 4 cores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/04/30/intermittent-quot-http-403-forbidden-quot-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-web-app.aspx) post explains why this happens and how to solve it